# New entity property names using FOS Rest and Nelmio Docs

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm creating a REST API in Symfony2 using FOS REST and Nelmio docs.

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  description="Create a new Object",
 *  input="Your\Namespace\Form\Type\YourType",
 *  output="Your\Namespace\Class"
 * )
 */
public function postAction()
{
}
```

Unfortunately this returns the output Class database field names, not the Class property names.  We want our users to have consistent, descriptive and nice property names that we set in the entity Class, rather than our legacy field names in the database.

Similarly, when we GET the Class object, the wrong field names are in the returned object.  Any thoughts on how to change this?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your entity model? I'm not sure what is the issue here. Could you also post an screenshot of Nelmio's output?